# Story about earth children playing with alien toys. Who wrote it?

Tags: languages, story-identification

I remember reading what I believe is a short story about a brother and sister who somehow come into possession of some toys which turn out to be from aliens. Through playing with them they develop a language their parents can't understand and start to develop mentally far faster than any human.

Does anyone recognize this story, or remember who wrote it or what it's called?

Comment: The toys are actually from far-future post-humans. Might as well have been aliens ;-)

Comment: @Martin - Where did you see that? Just curious, as I didn't get that impression when I reread the story.

Comment: I don't know that that's what the original story said. It was in the movie.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Aha!  I found it!  It's called ["Mimsy Were the Borogoves"](http://mimsyweretheborogoves.webs.com/index.htm) by Lewis Padgett (pseudoynm).  It's even cooler sounding than I remembered!

Wikipedia: [Mimsy Were the Borogoves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimsy_Were_the_Borogoves)

Comment: What an intriguing idea for a story, I had never heard of it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: There was also a feature film based on this story: The Last Mimzy http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0768212/

Comment: @TonyMeyer - thanks for the pointer to the film - I had no idea it existed.  This was a favorite story of mine as a kid.

Comment: The movie bore little resemblance to the short story.